# The type or namespace could not be found (but it should be!)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, namespaces

I would like to differentiate my DTO's from my model entities by using namespaces instead of adding the `Dto` suffix. So instead of having `Customer` and `CustomerDto`, having `Customer` and `DTO.Customer`.

Here's my code, pretty self explanatory.

```
namespace MyCompany.DAL
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}

using MyCompany.DAL;
namespace MyCompany.BLL
{
    public class CustomerService : EntityService<Customer>, ICustomerService
    {
        IContext _context;
        public CustomerService(IContext context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _dbset = _context.Set<Customer>();
        }

        // I can use DTO.Customer here without an issue, 
        // and Intellisense knows it's a namespace
        public DTO.Customer GetById(int Id) 
        {
            return _dbset.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
        }
    }
}

namespace MyCompany.DTO
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}

using MyCompany.BLL;
namespace MyCompany.API.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : ApiController
    {
        ICustomerService customerService;
        public CustomerController(ICustomerService customerService)
        {
            this.customerService = customerService;
        }

        // GET: api/Customer/5
        // [ResponseType(typeof(DTO.Customer))] 
        // Can't compile, 'The type or namespace name 'DTO' could not be found'
        [ResponseType(typeof(MyCompany.DTO.Customer))] // This works
        public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            var customer = customerService.GetById(id);
            return Ok(customer);
        }
    }
}
```

`BLL` project has a reference to both `DAL` and `DTO` projects. 
`API` project has a reference to both `DLL` and `DTO` projects.

Why can't I use `DTO.Customer` in my API controller in exactly the same way as I'm using it in my `CustomerService` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get away with namespace aliasing for one of the namespaces to save you from fully qualifying one of them:

```
using Co = MyCompany.Dto;
```

You can then do things in your code like:

```
var customerA = new Customer(); // from your most used namespace
var customerB = new Co.Customer(); // from your least used namespace
```

These are still different namespaces, and not the same object, as you've pointed out. They do NOT, and should not translate to eachother. The whole point with DTO's is to avoid corruption :)

**Automapper to the rescue**

I suggest that you have a quick look at [automapper](http://automapper.org/), which is a fantastic tool for converting a dto into a similar object.

Would that help you out?

Comment: Indeed, and I also managed to submit the entire thing halfway :) Thanks for the dot fix  :)

Comment: That is very interesting, I added `using DTO = MyCompany.DTO;` and now it works using `DTO.Customer` just like in the service. But I still would like to know why it isn't working in the first place?

Comment: Well, if you try to specify "Using" for two namespaces that both declare the same Customer object, then of course, the compiler will never know which one that you're thinking of when you type "customer". PS: Don't forget to flag the answer as answered if you're happy! :)

Comment: I already am using AutoMapper and it's great. I don't need it in my controller, though, since I'm doing all my mappings in the BLL. The only reason why I'm trying to use `DTO.Customer` in my controller instead of `Customer` (which I could use adding `using MyCompany.DTO;`) is to avoid any possible confusion among other developers (since my model is also named `Customer`).

Comment: Yup - the compiler will see them as two distinct objects - internally, it sees the entire namespace of each, which is why the alias helps you out. And your co-developers will also see that this customer is not the same as the other, so everyone should be happy :)

Comment: But I am not using two namespaces that both declare `Customer`, right? In my controller, I'm only using `MyCompany.BLL`, and within that namespace there's not another `Customer` class declared. The other `Customer` is in the `MyCompany.DAL` namespace, which is referenced in the `MyCompany.BLL` and added to the `usings` in the `CustomerService` class. Is this where the confusion is at?

Comment: You need to declare the namespace that defines the customer object in your controller namespace. The BLL does not declare a customer in your code. Only the DAL and the DTO namespaces do. In your controller, you're referencing  only the BLL namespace, but you want an object from the DTO namespace

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
using MyCompany.BLL;

using MyCompany; //<--- Add this

namespace MyCompany.API.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : ApiController
    {
        ...
    }
}
```